# build succeeds publish fails visual studio 2012 WPF project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a WPF project that I normally publish for click once installs
The project stopped publishing about 3 days ago.

If I build and/or run the project from code it succeeds but publish fails.
Cannot publish because a project failed to build.       1   1   ProjectName
Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\ProjectName.exe'.    ProjectName

Funny thing is if I look in the obj\x86\Debug folder it appears to put the ProjectName.exe in for a split second and then remove it again before failing.

The error in the output window is:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3075,5): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\ProjectName.exe'.

Error: Cannot publish because a project failed to build.

I've tried the normal stuff like cleaning, rebuilding, rebooting

After changing verbosity of build to diagnostics I got following information on the failure:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3075,5): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\ProjectName.exe'.
>
> Done executing task "GenerateApplicationManifest" -- FAILED. (TaskId:147)
>
> Done building target "GenerateApplicationManifest" in project "ProjectName.vbproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:166)

Comment: Have you tried turning up the verbosity of the build output? `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity`. Might give you a better idea of the issue.

Comment: @paul will try that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to discover the answer by following paul's suggestion.
I increased the verbosity of the build project via Tools | Options | Projects And Solution | Build and Run | Project build output verbosity.

Once I looked at the more verbose build output fixing the problem was simple.

The verbose output gave me exactly where the publish was failing so I was then able to fix those problems.

Comment: So what was the problem..?